# Can one be electrocuted when cleaning a light switch?

Tags: current, switches

Light switches are allegedly [some of the dirtiest spots in a house](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/12/14/clean-a-light-switch_n_2294132.html), and cleaning them is recommended in many articles. However the safety angle doesn't seem to get coevered. The only thing I could find was some [Australian work safety presentation](http://www.safework.sa.gov.au/uploaded_files/2E4LAvoidZap.pdf) which states:

> do not touch with wet hands
>
> pay attention to wet cleaning

What about wet feet? And pay attention to what, exactly? All disinfectants I know are "wet".
Should I just skip cleaning them?
Or maybe shut down the power in my apartment before (seems a bit extreme)?
Or maybe I could use some brush with an isolating handle?

I guess these questions stand for other switches as well (say, water heater ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wall switches are designed to be reasonably safe, at least under sensible conditions of (ab)use (with the cover plate on, of course).

In general, don't spray cleaner or similar liquid of any kind *into* a switch-- rather you should spray the cleaner onto a rag and wipe the switch operator and cover plate with the damp (not dripping) rag. Ordinary disinfectant should be fine if the label says you can use it on plastic, but solvents are a no-no as they could attack the plastic and embrittle or dissolve it.

There's no reason to turn off power on any properly wired residential switch I've ever seen for everyday cleaning (at least in the first world, I've seem some pretty dodgy stuff in the 3rd world including open knife switches with 240VAC/50Hz exposed).

Comment: Thanks, upvoted! (Interesting how your answer was voted up and my question down - would be nice if you could up it back to 0 so I can get some more opinions on this)